# String replace method not doing anything in Flex 4 app

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, string, replace, flex4

I have a string called userEmail in my Flex 4 app that has a value of:

```
my%40email.com
```

I need to have an @ symbol instead of %40, so I run this line:

```
userEmail.replace("%40","@");
```

But the string has the same value after. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `replace` is not an in-situ function. It returns a new string with the changed value. Try:

```
userMail = userEmail.replace("%40","@");
```

instead.

See [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/String.html#replace%28%29) for the gruesome details ([here](http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/String.html#replace%28%29) for flex4 but it appears to be the same).

Comment: Ah my brain must still be sleeping to not think of that! Thanks so much for your help.